# ImportXML Google Spreadsheet Alexa Ranking Checker

Tags: google-sheets, xpath, google-docs, alexa-internet

Attempting to parse Alexa ranking within Google Doc using =ImportXML. The following **works** and displays the Global rank:

```
=value(ImportXML(CONCATENATE("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=",$A$4),"//@rank[1]"))
```

In *theory* the following should display the country ranking if it exists: (this doesn't work)

```
=ImportXML(CONCATENATE("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=",$A$4),"//@rank[2]")
```

The above is the part that isn't working. It's not pulling the value of the second "rank" attribute.

I have also tried: (doesn't work)

```
=ImportXML(CONCATENATE("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&dat=snbamz&url=",$A$4),"/country/@rank")
```

Help? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the resultant XML?

Comment: Can you also provide full website link from where you are importing.

Comment: Alexa seem to have changed the XML since then. `//@rank[1]` did not work for me. I used the following for Global Rank and it worked: `//*/POPULARITY/@TEXT`

Answer (score 1):

Your second XPath query *may never work*. You're trying to query the second `@rank` attribute of an element, but there may only be one. If you want to select the second `@rank` attribute in the whole document, use `(//@rank)[2]`.

Your alternative query does not work, as `country` is not the root element. Use `//country/@rank` instead. It might be reasonable to provide the full path step by step, to prevent fetching the wrong elements/attributes (if they occur somewhere else in the document):

```
/alexa/sd/country/@rank
```

Please be aware that principally XPath is case sensitive, although Google Spreadsheet seems to be not. Better use all caps here, as the XML input does.

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error, I arrived at the following solution, accurate as of 2014-02-17.

```
=ImportXML(CONCAT("http://data.alexa.com/data?cli=10&url=", "www.google.com"), "number(//COUNTRY[@code='US']/@rank)")
```

Observations:

- tags appear to be case-sensitive
- attributes must be lower-case

Comment: I'd also like to add that I have better luck with this XPath: `number(//POPULARITY/@text)` as some sites don't have a US ranking (e.g. www.recycler.com)